# Constrain two lists to begin with N consecutive elements in total using CLP(FD)

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I am trying to constrain two lists to begin with `N` consecutive elements (`E`) in total using CLP(FD). Here's an example: let `L1` and `L2` be two lists of size 6, the elements belong to the domain `[0, 1]`, `E = 1`, and `N = 3`, then the predicate `constraint(+L1, +L2, +N)` would provide the following possible solutions:

```
L1 = [1, 1, 1, 0, _, _], L2 = [0, _, _, _, _, _];
L1 = [1, 1, 0, _, _, _], L2 = [1, 0, _, _, _, _];
L1 = [1, 0, _, _, _, _], L2 = [1, 1, 0, _, _, _];
L1 = [0, _, _, _, _, _], L2 = [1, 1, 1, 0, _, _].
```

For lists of size 3, the following would be acceptable:

```
L1 = [1, 1, 1], L2 = [0, _, _];
L1 = [1, 1, 0], L2 = [1, 0, _];
L1 = [1, 0, _], L2 = [1, 1, 0];
L1 = [0, _, _], L2 = [1, 1, 1].
```

I eventually want to generalize this to an arbitrary number of lists and domain, but this is the smallest equivalent problem I could think of.

---

Here's my (failed) attempt so far:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

constseq([], _, 0).
constseq([L|_], A, 0) :- L #\= A.
constseq([A|Ls], A, N) :- N1 #= N - 1, constseq(Ls, A, N1).

constraint(L1, L2, N) :-
  SL1 + SL2 #= N,
  constseq(L1, 1, SL1),
  constseq(L2, 1, SL2).

main(L1, L2) :-
  length(L1, 6),
  length(L2, 6),
  constraint(L1, L2, 3).
```

Although it works, note that I'm generating the solutions through *backtracking*, and not taking advantage of CLP(FD) to do the dirty job. I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish this, and I'm already looking at predicates like `chain/2`, and monsters like `automaton/3`, but something in me tells that there must be a simpler solution to this...

Comment: Please remove the `format/2`, and make this accessable via **arguments**. For example, `main(L1, L2) :- ...`. You cannot test output that only appears on the terminal, at least not as easily as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired on SICStus [example](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/3.7.1/html/sicstus_33.html#SEC255) of `exactly/3`, here's my latest attempt:

```
constseq_(_, [], _, 0).
constseq_(X, [Y|L], F, N) :-
  X #= Y #/\ F #<=> B,
  N #= M+B,
  constseq_(X, L, B, M).

constseq(L, E, N) :-
  constseq_(E, L, 1, N).
```

Comment: Good step in the right direction, but currently too general. You can combine constraint reification with `automaton/8`!

Comment: `automaton/8` seems even more scaring that `automaton/3`. What would be the advantages of using it over the above solution? Where does it fail? In which way do you think it is too general?

Comment: What about lists of the form `[1,1,1,0,1,1]`? In any case, you are using a too complex example in my view. Consider filing a question for a *single* list, and describing that correctly. Then, let us come back here to discuss the version where *two* lists are described.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it as follows (using [ECLiPSe](http://eclipseclp.org) with [library(ic)](http://www.eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/ic/index.html)):

```
:- lib(ic).
:- lib(ic_global).

constraint(Xs, Ys, N) :-
    Xs #:: 0..1,
    Ys #:: 0..1,
    sum(Xs) + sum(Ys) #= N,
    ordered(>=, Xs),
    ordered(>=, Ys).
```

which gives the desired solutions:

```
?- length(Xs,6), length(Ys,6), constraint(Xs,Ys,3), labeling(Xs), labeling(Ys).
Xs = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Ys = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 1, maybe more) ? ;
Xs = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Ys = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 2, maybe more) ? ;
Xs = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Ys = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 3, maybe more) ? ;
Xs = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
Ys = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Yes (0.00s cpu, solution 4)
```

Comment: Very elegant, but it misses solutions such as Xs = [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] and Ys = [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]. That's why I used `_`'s in the specification.